# Laravel 4.2 Composer install error: "could not scan for classes"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I want to install on my new Laravel 4.2 installation some packages via Composer. However, I am getting an exception.

This is my Composer file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "license": "MIT",   
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "zizaco/confide": "~4.0@dev",
        "zizaco/entrust": "1.2.*@dev",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "1.*",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "1.3.*@dev",
        "bllim/datatables": "~1.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "~1.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "way/generators": "~2.6",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "~1.11"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/controllers/admin",
            "app/controllers/user"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd":[
            "php artisan ide-helper:generate"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

When running `composer install` I get:

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.jso
n. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files



  [RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "app/controllers/admin" which does not ap
  pear to be a file nor a folder



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-p
lugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--ver
bose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

This is  basically a fresh Laravel installation. Why do I get the error:

```
Could not scan for classes inside "app/controllers/admin" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
```

**UPDATE**

Using `composer update`:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing mockery/mockery (0.9.2)
  - Removing phpunit/phpunit (4.3.4)
  - Removing phpunit/php-code-coverage (2.0.11)
  - Removing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.3.0)
  - Removing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.3.4)
  - Removing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.5)
  - Removing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (2.3.0)
  - Removing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.0)
  - Removing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.4)
  - Removing symfony/yaml (v2.5.6)
  - Removing sebastian/comparator (1.0.1)
  - Removing sebastian/diff (1.2.0)
  - Removing sebastian/environment (1.2.0)
  - Removing sebastian/exporter (1.0.2)
  - Removing sebastian/version (1.0.3)
  - Removing summerstreet/woodling (v0.1.6)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files



  [RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "app/controllers/admin" which does not ap
  pear to be a file nor a folder



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock]
 [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-
dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [
packagesN]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `composer update`. That is what it says in the error.

```
...You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them...
```

**Update:**

Composer is trying to find the folder `app/controllers/admin` which is no standard folder in laravel. Are you sure this folder exists? If not, you could try removing these, and other custom folders, from the composer.json, and add them manually. You could also create the directories and leave the composer.json untouched.

Comment: Thx for your answer! When running `composer update` i get the same error, pls hava a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Are you sure the class folders in your composer.json exist? I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

for laravel 8 in year 2021, add folder admin in controller if not exist and
go to composer.json and change classmap to

```
  "classmap": [
        "app/http/controllers/admin"
    ]
```